# Fullcalendar coloring specific cells

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

Hi I'm trying to color a specific cells in Fullcalendar with resource View.

```
tr.fc-slot13 {
background-color: #D6D6D6 !important;
}
```

this one, can give a color to whole row. But i want only two first columns for.e.

i possible to do that in Fullcalnedar?

I use **FullCalendar v1.6.4 with Resource View extension**.

http://screenshot.cz/OD7M0/ this is how i want it looks like.

Comment: you can use nth child to do that

Answer (score 1):

```
tr.fc-slot13:nth-child(1) {
background-color: #D6D6D6 !important;
}

tr.fc-slot13:nth-child(2) {
background-color: #D6D6D6 !important;
}
```

if it is only for finite number